# JPA persistence.xml META-INF placement folder

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, eclipse-wtp, persistence.xml

I currently have my persistence.xml located in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml. Also I am using eclipselink 2.4 as my JPA 2.0 implementation.

[image]

After publishing to the server and trying to run the app in the browser I get the following error:

```
Exception: : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit named 'X'
is available in scope Webapp. Available persistence units: [] at
```

This is ONLY when building in Eclipse. Leaving META-INF on the path src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml and performing maven install to build the war file, the META-INF folder is correctly placed in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml like it should be (inside the war). Seems that it is only and issue of when the webapp is built and ran locally in Eclipse. Can anyone explain this?

Can anyone explain what the problem is? Maybe someone has ran into this problem before?

Comment: did you build the war within eclipse with m2eclipse or directly via eclipse?

Comment: I used the M2E-WTP plugin. Right click project -> Run As -> Maven install.